# Extract base model prediction H2o stacked model mojo

Tags: java, h2o, mojo, ensembles

Is it possible to extract base models prediction given the final stacked ensemble mojo model using java in production for scoring

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently supported, but we should support it, so I created a [JIRA ticket](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8044) (you can follow the ticket for progress/updates).